# Using profile attributes for personalization in multi org structure

Tags: profile

we are having a multi org env where we are connected to two different salescloud instances. The parent BU is connected to one sales cloud instance and the contact data from salescloud is imported into marketing cloud DE's and the emails are send from DEs. However the other salescloud instance is mapped to one of the child BU and we are planning to use campaigns of salescloud to send the emails without importing the contact data. In this process we are using profile attributes for personalization in the emails send from MC. Will using the profile attributes in multi org structure works

Comment: What exactly you need?Can you please be more Specific?

Comment: Samir we are having a multi org env where we are connected to two different salescloud instances. The parent BU is connected to one sales cloud instance and the contact data from salescloud is imported into marketing cloud DE's and the emails are send from DEs. However the other salescloud instance is mapped to one of the child BU and we are plannig to use campaings of salescloud to send the emails without importing the contact data. In this process we are using profile attributes for personalization in the emails send from MC. Will using the profile attributes in multi org structure works

Comment: @Vishnu you should [edit](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/162616/edit) your question, and add the details from your comment.

Comment: Done. Thank you.